# Android OssLicensesMenuActivity crashes on start

Tags: android

I have added every needed dependency and plugins. My project is also generating third_party_licences files, but my app crashes when activity OssLicensesMenuActivity starts.
Errors here:

E/GmsClient: unable to connect to service: com.google.android.gms.oss.licenses.service.START on com.google.android.gms
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.axabee.seeplaces, PID: 12102
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'long com.google.android.gms.internal.oss_licenses.zzc.zze()' on a null object reference
at com.google.android.gms.internal.oss_licenses.zze.zza(Unknown Source:19)
at com.google.android.gms.oss.licenses.zzf.onComplete(Unknown Source:28)
at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzj.run(Unknown Source:4)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)